# compareTo method for String in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write very simple codes for comparing below Strings with compareTo method but I have an issue of ordering it in alphabetical order with compareTo method.

String: {BANANA, CAT, BEAR}.

Rather than breaking it up into each starting letter, is there any possible way to arrange them in alphabetic order with compareTo method specifically? (so it should be ordered as BANANA, BEAR and CAT).

Thanks!

---

Below is the extraction of my method.

```
public void removeMaximumValues(int N) {
        if (N < 0) { 
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            Node current = head;
            Node maxNode = null;
            int greatestDiff = 0;

            //EXTRACT the MaxNode
            while (current != null) {
                if (head.value.compareTo(current.value) < greatestDiff) {
                    greatestDiff = head.value.compareTo(current.value);
                    maxNode = current;
                }
                current = current.next;
            }
.
.
.
//test
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyLinkedList myList = new MyLinkedList();
        myList.add("BANANA");
        myList.add("CAT");
        myList.add("BEAR");
    ... //then I want to pull "CAT" out of the LinkedList with compareTo method
```

Comment: Add them to an `ArrayList` and then call `sort`?

Comment: Can you show some code or libraries you've attempted to use and what the results were?

Comment: They are actually the elements of LinkedList and what I ultimately want to do is to pull out the "largest value" of String, which is "CAT" in this case... @Yserbius I posted some parts of my codes above

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your `LinkedList` with

```
Collections.sort(myList);
```

Maximum element (By lexical means) will be at the last index, so you can access it as

```
String max = myList.get(myList.size-1);
```

Comment: @Manziel Thanks, I am comparing BANANA to CAT and BEAR respectively, but this returns BEAR as the largest value instead of CAT. Does your last statement mean that I should compare every element to another with compareTo method? If so, that may be how I am doing it now.. my variable name is poorly named sorry but greatestDiff basically refers to the current return value of the method, with BANANA being anchored.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you take the "greatest diff" but compareTo does not necessarily work the way that A.compareTo(B) < A.compareTo(C)
The only guarantee you get is

```
A.compareTo(B) < 0  ---> A < B
A.compareTo(B) == 0 ---> A == B
A.compareTo(B) > 0  ---> A > B
```

This means you always have to compare your current maximum against the next element